# mousePressed not updating within while loop

Tags: processing

Posted this on the Processing forum but got no help.

I want to know why the following doesn't work:

```
void setup(){
  size(400,400);
}

void draw(){
  while (true) {
    if (mousePressed == true) {break;}
  }
  println("OK");
}
```

`mousePressed` doesn't update to `true` during a click, which means the draw loop never prints `"OK"`. Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mousePressed` variable is only updated between subsequent calls to `draw()`.

Repeatedly testing a variable that cannot change will always fail.

Comment: So if i'm understanding you correctly, the mousePressed function is not an interrupt, but a poll performed at the start of draw()? Could you link to any documentation describing this because my search turned up empty.

Comment: The interrupts are processed by the OS, and sent out to programs via a message pump. Frameworks like processing, receive those messages and apply them to variables for use each time the main loop is run(this is hidden from the user prospective).  This process eliminates volatility and concurrency issues in the variables. I have been unable to locate any processing specific documentation to support this claim.  I have spent the remaining time trying(almost an hour) to find a reference to this in the source code. Your own test should be poof enough.